# How to set DPI (dots per inch) in PDFsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

Is there any way to set DPI (dots per inch) in case of PDFsharp?

Thanks

Comment: If you are including images on a page, you can always rescale them with an external tool prior to using them.

Comment: You can also use .NET framework routines for that job. Depends on the task (one-time job or application).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, PDF files are vector files that have no DPI.

If your question is about images stored in the PDFfile:

PDFsharp stores images as they come. PDFsharp does not (yet) resize images to lower DPI to reduce the file size. Your application knows which image will be used where and at which size, so you should reduce the raster images to the DPI (*) you need before using them with PDFsharp.

Please note that images will be included in the PDF only once, even if they are drawn several times - and they can be drawn at different size (e.g. large company logo on first page, smaller on subsequent pages).

I hope I answered the question. If not, please explain what you are asking for.

(*) calculate pixel width and height of images based on the size they will have on the PDF page and the DPI you want; some raster images have a DPI setting, but this does not affect image file size.